# iPhone: Where NSUserDefaults get stored?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am able to store, retrieve, and remove values using NSUserDefaults. I couldn't succeed to find out where NSUserDefaults getting stored physically on iPhone? I guess it should be plist file but not sure. Does anyone know if its possible to see this values on iPhone physically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- Connect Your device to Xcode.
- Select `Windows` -> `Organiser`.
- Select your device.
- Click on your application.
- Click the gear icon and `Download Container…`.
- Select the downloaded `.xcappdata` file, right click and select `Show Package Contents`.
- Open the `AppData` folder.
- Navigate to `Library` -> `Preferences` -> `appbundlename.plist`.

Answer (score 8):

The physical path is rootOfApplication/Library/Preferences/com.yourcompany.appName.plist you can see there if you test it in simulator

Answer (score 0):

I use SimSim. It's a free menu bar app that gives you access to all simulator folders. There are other solutions, but this is a basic tool I use all the time. https://github.com/dsmelov/simsim

Answer (score 0):

Small differences to the accepted answer for Xcode 14.

- Connect Your device to Xcode.
- Select `Window` -> `Devices and Simulators`.
- Select the `Devices` tab in the sidebar.
- Select your device.
- Select your application from the `INSTALLED APPS` section.
- Click the encircled ellipsis icon and select `Download Container…` and `Save` the file.
- In the `Finder` select the downloaded `.xcappdata` file, right click and select `Show Package Contents`.
- The plist file is in the package's `Appdata` -> `Preferencers` -> `Library`.