# How can I access a user's data for our iOS app?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, documentsdirectory

We have a bug in our released iOS app that we cannot reproduce and is only affecting a small amount of users. I'm currently in contact with a couple users that are willing to help but I need a way to get all of the data they have in our app so they can send it to us. Is there a way for them to make a backup of the app and send it to us?

Info I need includes the Private Documents directory and their NSUserDefaults data. I know I can use iExplorer to get access to their Private Documents directory but getting their NSUserDefaults info is proving to be a little more tricky.

Comment: The `NSUserDefaults` is stored as a plist file in "<path-to-app>/Library/Preferences/<app-bundle-id>.plist".

Comment: This worked! Using iExplorer I can have the user send us all their files. If you want to make an answer I'll select yours as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the physical device then you can use the following steps provided in the question [iPhone: Where NSUserDefaults get stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662679/iphone-where-nsuserdefaults-get-stored):

- Connect Your device to xcode
- select Windows->Organiser
- select you device
- tap on your application
- select applicationData tapping down list
- tap down arrow and download that folder
- open downloaded folder
- Library -> Preferences -> appbundlename.plist

If you don't have physical access to the device then I would just create a small update for your app, which includes code to access `NSUserDefaults` and upload it to a remote server. You would just ask your users to install this update and then you'd have access to their local device data.