# NSuserdefaults Location

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I cant find location of nsuserdefaults for my app.
 In [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults) solution was /users/your user name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator//Applications. But i have no  in iPhone Simulatar dir.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662679/iphone-where-nsuserdefaults-get-stored

Comment: im using Simulator, not real device. also symbols in angle brackets was deleted...

Comment: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can do this**

Search for documents directory path

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSLog(@"documentsDirectory=%@",documentsDirectory);
```

**That will come as**

```
   /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/270568AE-FB4B-4C57-8819-4D99324D0689/data/Containers/Data/Application/C614A497-971F-4686-9162-3A614AB2C702/Documents
```

**now go upto**

```
 /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/270568AE-FB4B-4C57-8819-4D99324D0689/data/Containers/Data/Application/C614A497-971F-4686-9162-3A614AB2C702
```

**Then**

```
/Library/Preferences/....plist
```

.plist file stores NSUserdefaults content under Root .

Comment: i found the .../Prefernces folder, which was created today, but its empty, i checked with sudo ls

Comment: use     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"Test"];
then check plist file will be created.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Simulator, you can use this swift snippet to print the location :

`dump(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])`

Comment: This is incorrect. The plist file for UserDefaults is not stored in the app's Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

The physical path is rootOfApplication/Library/Preferences/**com.yourcompany.appName.plist** you can see there if you test it in simulator

and the **workflow** is

1.Connect Your device to Xcode

2.select Windows->Organiser

3.select you device

4.tap on your application

5.select applicationData tapping down list

6.tap down arrow and download that folder

7.open downloaded folder
Library -> Preferences -> appbundlename.plist

Comment: there is no com.yourcompany.anyMyApp.plist in rootOfApplication/Library/Preferences/

Comment: the reverse DNS that you give in the beginning. I give for example com.kumar  so forth, at the time of creating your app.

Comment: in this dir only com.apple* and com.adobe* plists

Answer (score 0):

for here:

debugging `iOS 14.3` `iPhone8` for `WhatsApp`, the `NSUserDefaults` location for `suiteName`=`group.net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.shared` is:

- `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D70C70AC-D347-4640-9667-1AA86D05CB65/Library/Preferences/group.net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.shared.plist`

  - [image: whatsapp NSUserDefaults]