# Possible to export userdefaults plist as email attachment in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, plist, userdefaults

In Xcode userdefaults are saved in a plist. I'd like to export this file directly. Is it possible?

There are a couple of answers on finding it in the simulator, but I'm interested in finding it on the  device while using the app and attaching it to email.

Possible?

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate. Those answers tell you how to find the plist on the MAC when running the app in the simulator. As I stated originally, I'm looking for a way to attach the file while running the app on the device.

I haven't been able to find any ways to do that directly. So far looks like I'll just have to parse it and export it via another format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662679/iphone-where-nsuserdefaults-get-stored

Comment: You can also do `let dicitionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()`, filter some key/values if needed, transform it into a file of your representation choice (like a JSON file, a Plist file, an XML one, etc) and then send it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: Where NSUserDefaults get stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662679/iphone-where-nsuserdefaults-get-stored)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because those answers tell you how to find the plist in your MAC on the simulator. I'm looking for a way to get the file in the device while using the app.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for you recommendation. I'll do that.